# Can a wordpress website be used as mobile app backend?

Tags: wordpress, backend, mobile-application

I have a project where I need to make a mobile app for a wordpress website. It will have some features that are not in the web app yet. I've made some research and there seems to be ways to make api requests to some endpoints that are made available by wordpress. I am a rookie when it comes to planning a backend structure, building it from scratch, and deploying it, but I have developed new features for an existing node.js backend for a mobile app before. Considering all of this, can I use the wordpress api for my mobile app without any security, performance, or compatibility issues or should I start building a backend for it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we can use WordPress website for mobile application backend.
For this we need to make an API request according to WordPress structure and database structure.
A new development in WordPress is the WP-API, which allows you to output your site content into a standardized JSON API. Since mobile apps normally use an API to get remote data, using the WP-API is a great way to get your WordPress data into a mobile app.

We can use inbuilt plugins for the same purpose like AppPreser- Mobile App Framework.